# How to modify context menu

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian-wheezy, context-menu

On my raspberry pi, I was trying to get a file to play, but both mplayer and omxplayer did not show up in the "Others" list when I tried to associate the file with the players, so I typed it in using the "custom command line". Both mplayer and omxplayer refused to display video, so I got VLC.

Now Im stuck with:

[image: this]

I think that the file manager is pcmanfm, but I have been unable to find out how to remove file associations.

Comment: What file manager are you using? Also, why shouldn't I mark this as offtopic?

Comment: Because this is a "user question" as opposed to a programming question or something else. And I'm not sure what file manager Im using. It's whatever is default on the raspberry pi. It might be nautilis. I normally use the pi headless, but I was exploring TightVNC when this happened.

Comment: `ps ax |grep nautilus`? Also, SE don't allow cross posting question, please delete your question on raspberrypi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I finally found that the file manager is pcmanfm, and that the config file is at `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.config`, which I modified to get rid of the extra menu options

Comment: 2 years later my pcmanfm file was a slightly different name: ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list I wouldn't have found it without your original location.

Comment: For me, on pi 3 raspbian jessie, it was `~/.config/mimeapps.list`

Answer (score 1):

I had done same thing with my Pi3 (Raspbian) and omxplayer.

My answer based on what I learned above:

cd ./.local/share/applications

ls -a (userapp-omxplayer --win 60,60,450,280-QGTR0Z.desktop looked like the one I wanted to delete.)

nano "./userapp-omxplayer --win 60,60,450,280-QGTR0Z.desktop" (inspected contents to make sure I had right one)

rm "userapp-omxplayer --win 60,60,450,280-QGTR0Z.desktop" (removed it)

RMB on file type in a directory verified unwanted entry is gone.

I could have modified while in nano, but I had created a duplicate, so I deleted it.